# Building Firefox Addons and deploying them from GitHub

Tags: firefox, github, firefox-addon

Is it possible to use GitHub and if necessary my own vServer to build and deploy Firefox Addons to [their official platform](http://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/)? If so, how?

I like GitHub because everyone can fork/pull requests and help coding. Now, I would like to host my firefox addon code on GitHub, but deploy it on their official addons platform...

Comment: There are no automatic "deployment" mechanisms for Firefox add-ons. From the sound of your question, I guess that you've been using the Add-on Builder?

Comment: Don't know this "Add-on Builder" ;-) I need to know what's the most common way to host code on GitHub and deploy on firefox addons platform. The way which causes least work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host your code anywhere, it doesn't really matter. However, an automated "deployment" will be hard - addons.mozilla.org doesn't support automated uploads. You can write a script that will get the source from GitHub and package it as a Firefox extension (meaning little more than packing it up with a ZIP compressor) but then you will have to authenticate on addons.mozilla.org and upload the package manually.